# Java 8 Streams int and Integer

Tags: java, integer, int, java-8, java-stream

Was just getting my hands dirty with Java 8 and stumbled on a behaviour as below -

```
public static void main(String... args){
    System.out.println("[Start]");
    int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Stream.of(ints).forEach(i->System.out.println("Int : "+i));


    Integer[] integerNums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Stream.of(integerNums).forEach(i->System.out.println("Integer : "+i));

    System.out.println("[End]");
}
```

And the output is :

```
[Start]
Int : [I@5acf9800
Integer : 1
Integer : 2
Integer : 3
Integer : 4
[End]
```

Whereas I was expecting the code to print all int's and Integer's in both the cases? Any insights on this would be greatly helpful...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generics don't work with primitive types. The `Stream.of` method is declared as

```
static <T> Stream<T> of(T... values)
```

When you use

```
Stream.of(ints)
```

where `ints` is an `int[]`, Java doesn't see a number of `int` elements (primitive types), it sees a single `int[]` element (which is a reference type). So the single `int[]` is bound as the only element in the array represented by `T... values`.

So `values` becomes an `int[][]` and each of its elements is an `int[]`, which print like

```
[I@5acf9800
```

Comment: You can use `IntStream.of` for ints.