# int [] (integer array) and object class relation in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I know Object class is the root class of all classes in Java,
I wanted to know the relation between int[] and Object class.

Arrays.stream() can accept arg of int[], long[], double[] and Object[].

As I came across a code which gives int[] to a generic type (`Stream<int[]>`), This code works, we provide only class to Stream.

Also the output to this code was hex code rather than integers

```
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

        // --------- Using Arrays.stream() --------- 

        // to convert int array into Stream 
        IntStream intStream = Arrays.stream(arr); 

        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        intStream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " ")); // {1,2,3,4,5]

        // --------- Using Stream.of() --------- 

        // to convert int array into Stream 
        Stream<int[]> stream = Stream.of(arr); 

        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        stream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " ")); // I@asdf
```

Comment: What's your question? What's the error you want to fix? what's the expected output?

Comment: answer to title can be found in [JLS 10. Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-10.html). First sentence: *"In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array."*

Comment: @user15244370 Thank You so much, was searching for this

Comment: just for *fun* `System.out.println(arr.getClass())` or `Object obj = arr; int[] casted = (int[]) obj;`

Comment: syso(arr.getClass()) // "[I"
Makes sense toString() is Classname@hexcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `intStream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " "));` each `str` would be of type `int`. But in `stream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " "));` each `str` is of type `int[]`. Hence the difference in output.

To print a primitive array you need to use `Arrays.toString` like :

```java
stream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(str) + "\n"));
```

Comment: This answered cleared things as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949570/java-8-streams-int-and-integer
This cleared the concept